# Pygame Pixel Array generator

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, generator, pixel

I'm trying to draw functions and graphs using generators in Python (2.7.9), and found a problem: I can't flush my generated pixel data (RGB tuples) into a Pygame Pixel array. Here's my code (which i tryied to run):

1. using 2d arrays

   `pixArr = pygame.PixelArray(surface)
   pixArr=[[(0,0,function(x,y)) for x in range(1,screenX)] for y in range(1,screeny)]
   del pixArr`

Here i've realized that pixArr isn't a ordinary 2d list becouse of my failure to output it (print pixArr)

2. Then i've tryied using range

   `pixArr[0:screenX*screenY] = [(0,0,function(curPix%screenX, curPix//screenY)) for curPix in range(0,screenX*screenY)]`

I've found something like this code on pygame website [HERE](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html#pygame.PixelArray), but it gives me error "ValueError: sequence size mismatch", after playing around with it became clear that it works only with a single color (for example  `pixArr[0:screenX*screenY]=(0,0,255)` colors the whole screen blue)

TL;DR: How can I set each pixel without using loops

```
For y in range(0,1000):
    For x in range(0,1000):
        gfx.draw(surface,x,y,(0,0,function(a,b))) #or pixArr in this line
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using pygame 1.9.1, but it seems `PixelArrays` changed a lot on 1.9.2 so beware.

I just tried this example and it works fine:

```
pixArr = pygame.PixelArray(surface)
def f(i):
    return i % 255
pixArr[:] = [(0, 0, f(i)) for i in range(0, len(pixArr))]
```

One thing to notice is that doing:

```
pixArr = [(0, 0, f(i)) for i in range(0, len(pixArr))]
```

does NOT work because it converts the PixelArray variable into a list (as in your first snippet of code).

On why you are getting a `ValueError`, I just did some checks, and curiosly (and surpsiringly enough), I noticed that `len(pixArray)` is not equal to `pixArray.surface.get_width() * pixArray.surface.get_height()`.
I recomend you to do some checks on this before you go on.

--

EDIT:

I thought about sharing this new snippet I got to because it seems very interesting:

```
def f(i):
    return i % 255
length = len(pixArr)
length2 = len(pixArr[0])
print length, length2
for j in range(0, length):
    array = [(0, f(j), f(i)) for i in range(0, length2)]
    pixArr[j] = array
```

Comment: Found another bug: range(0, len(pixArr)) must be used insead of range(0, screenMaxX*ScreenMaxY)

Comment: Actually, looking up further, `len(pixArr) == surface.get_width()`, while `len(pixArr[i]) == surface.get_height()`

Comment: Exactly! Just found out about it. Pygames webpage on pixel arrays is stupidly inconsistent. For example, pixel arrays do not have "pygame.PixelArray.ndim — Returns the number of dimensions." method, unlike was written there.

Comment: ndim is one of the changes made from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2, the webpage makes that clear about it. It looks like most of the cool stuff PixelArray have, are new in 1.9.2